# What typings type should be for function?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

What should typings type (class, namespace or another ) be for function?

My JS file has next structure:

```
export function MyFunction(param1, param2) {

  const executeRequest = (payload) => { ... }
  this.on = (evt, cb) => { ... }
  this.off= (evt, cb) => { ... }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function appears to be a constructor function, since it accesses `this` but appears to be standalone. It assigns two members `on` and `off` which are functions. Not sure what `executeRequest` does, if it is just used inside the function you don't need to declare it on the public interface. So the definition I would use is:

```
declare class MyFunction {
    constructor(param1: any, param2: any);
    on: (evt: any, cb: any) => void;
    off: (evt: any, cb: any) => void;
}
// Usage
let o = new MyFunction(null, null)
```

You might consider replacing `any` if you know any of the types for the parameters but they are not clear from the posted code.

Comment: @MaxKarpovets how do you import the function ?

Comment: @MaxKarpovets I created a simple example .. and it worked for me. Are you sure the function is exported from the module ?